# Using IMVT? Limit of the sequence given by the integral

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I found this problem in a past exam and solve it. I want to know if I did it correctly because I used the mean value theorem for integrals (IMVT) and I'm not sure if it went the right way. Let $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, C^{1}: g\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=1, g'\left(x\right)>0\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$. Find (if possible) $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\cos\left(\frac{1}{a_{n}}\right)\sin\left(a_{n}\right)}{g\left(a_{n}+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}$ where $4a_{n}=\int_{3\pi}^{5\pi}\sin^{n}\left(\frac{t}{4}\right)g\left(\frac{t}{4}\right)dt$.

My work:

First, using the substitution $x=\frac{t}{4}$ we have that $a_{n}=\int_{\frac{3\pi}{4}}^{\frac{5\pi}{4}}\sin^{n}\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)dx$.

Second, $g$ is $C^{1}: g\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=1, g'\left(x\right)>0\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ which means that $g$ is continuous (thus integrable), monotonically increasing and positive at least from $\frac{\pi}{2}$ onwards. So, it that does not change sign on the interval $\left(\frac{3\pi}{4},\frac{5\pi}{4}\right)$. Also, for every fixed $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\sin^{n}\left(x\right)$ is $C^{\infty}$. Therefore, using the IMVT: $\int_{\frac{3\pi}{4}}^{\frac{5\pi}{4}}\sin^{n}\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)dx=\sin^{n}\left(c\right)\int_{\frac{3\pi}{4}}^{\frac{5\pi}{4}}g\left(x\right)dx$ where $c\in\left(\frac{3\pi}{4},\frac{5\pi}{4}\right)$.

Third, as $g$ is positive in $\left(\frac{3\pi}{4},\frac{5\pi}{4}\right)$, then $\int_{\frac{3\pi}{4}}^{\frac{5\pi}{4}}g\left(x\right)dx=A\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$ because it defines the area under its curve.

Also, $|\sin\left(c\right)|<1$ because $c\in\left(\frac{3\pi}{4},\frac{5\pi}{4}\right)$ so $\left(\sin\left(c\right)\right)^{n}\to0\:\left(n\to\infty\right)$. Thus, $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sin\left(c\right)\right)^{n}A=0$

Finally, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos\left(\frac{1}{a_{n}}\right)\frac{\sin\left(a_{n}\right)}{g\left(a_{n}+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}=0$ using the property “bounded . zero” in limits (consequence of the squeeze theorem).